# Looping through a 2D numpy array (e.g. to create a line)

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, multidimensional-array

I often find myself having to create a line (or some kind of other shape) within a 2D array. In other words, the value of the array is zero everywhere apart from where y = mx + c. *(Aside - the motivation for this approach, rather than storing a line in a 1D array, is that my work often requires 2D Fourier transform, and so I need the zeros everywhere apart from the line/shape/etc etc).*

My usual approach for doing this is the following:

```
array = numpy.zeros((height, width))
for i, line in enumerate(array):
    for j, pixel in enumerate(line):
         if j == m*i + c:
             array[i,j] = 1
```

This works fine, but it doesn't strike me as particularly pythonic, and it tends to get pretty slow when the array gets big. So, my question is a rather general one - does anybody know of a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions - all give the same result, and good to know about them all. I'm marking Oliver W. as correct, purely based on readability. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`np.fromfunction`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfunction.html) was designed for cases where an array can be constructed from the indices, such as this scenario.

In your case,

```
np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: j == m*i+c, (height, width), dtype=np.float)
```

would be equivalent to your approach, but using numpy's routines rather than Python for-loops.

Short demo:

```
import numpy as np
height, width = 10,10
m, c = 2, 4

a = np.zeros((height, width))
for i, line in enumerate(a):
    for j, pixel in enumerate(a):
         if j == m*i + c:
             a[i,j] = 1

b = np.fromfunction(lambda i, j: j == m*i+c, (height, width), dtype=np.float)

np.all(a==b)
# True
b.astype(np.int) # as type added to reduce output (no need for all the periods)
#array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Edit: Even though this answer got accepted, I want to point out that [@Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29537825/2476444) is about 10 times faster on my machine. If you're looking for speed: use that answer *if* your problem lends itself easily to vectorization, like Divakar showed (not every `fromfunction` call can be easily vectorized). I upvoted it, because it's a nice approach to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) here to get rid of those nested loops -

```
import numpy as np
out = (np.arange(height) == m*np.arange(width)[:,None]+c)+0.0
```

As an example to verify for correctness, with these parameters -

```
height = 10
width = 10
m = 0.5;
c = 6;
```

you would have -

```
In [306]: array
Out[306]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])

In [307]: out
Out[307]: 
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`np.put`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put.html),but you need to create the list of specific indices, that you can do it with a list comprehension :

```
>>> np.put(arr,[j for j in range(arr.shape[1]) for i in range(arr.shape[0]) if j == m*i + c],1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> np.put(arr,[j for j in range(arr.shape[1]) for i in range(arr.shape[0]) if j == 3*i + 1],1)
>>> arr
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
>>> np.put(arr,[j for j in range(arr.shape[1]) for i in range(arr.shape[0]) if j == 0.5*i + 2],1)
>>> arr
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
```